# How can I convert vector paths into points array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, vector-graphics

I'm trying to make the jump from processing to javascript. 
Usually I work on drawings machines, and to me are important two things: 
convert vector files into a series of points and send them via serial.

Right now I'm working on the first thing, but I can not find solutions. 
On processing, use Geomerative library, and there is a command called: 
[getPointsInPaths](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/geomerative/documentation/geomerative/RShape.html#getPointsInPaths%28%29)

Do you know a tool to do the same thing on JavaScript? 
I tried to look paperjs and raphaeljs, but without finding what I needed.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphael makes it very easy to either extract the vertices of a shape or sample its points at regular intervals:

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/L4xgj/2/):

[image]

```
// draw the shape normally
var shape = paper.path(path_str).transform("T-550,-50");

// get vertices of shape
shape.attrs.path.forEach(function(vertex) {
    paper.circle(vertex[1],vertex[2],1)
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .transform("T-400,-50");    
});

// get points at regular intervals
for (var c = 0; c < Raphael.getTotalLength(path_str); c += 5) {
    var point = Raphael.getPointAtLength(path_str, c);
    console.log(point);
    paper.circle(point.x,point.y,1)
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .transform("T-250,-50");    

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is very close to what I need, but there are two things I do not understand: 

in this case the svg is defined within the document, does exists in raphael a method to import it from outside the browser? 

With the first example, we only take the vertices of a polygon or we also can approximate drawings also composed of curves?

Comment: Sure: for shapes with curves, you'll want to use the latter method since "vertices" has a less clear meaning: http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/L4xgj/3/

If you want to extract the path from an SVG ahead of time instead of finding the string on the DOM, as I do in this example, use http://www.readysetraphael.com/